# Is my translation correct?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I translated "illuminate my heart/soul/mind" as "illuminas animus meus" in Latin. I know "animus" doesn't directly translates to heart but I want to express these 3 things in a word and it seems fit.

Do you have any better word recommendations and is this translation correct?

Answer (score 9):

Illuminare is a verb ending on -are. It follows the first verb conjugation, like *amare*. 
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_conjugation#First_conjugation

If you want to address one person, use illumina. If you want to address multiple persons, use illuminate (the plural version).

Imperatives usually (not always) come at the beginning of the utterance.

I think animus should be in the accusative case, because it is a direct object. Thus it should be animum.
See: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/animus

Meus (-a, -um) is a possessive pronoun. It is declined as an adjective of the first and second declension. So it should be meum.
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_declension#First-_and_second-declension_adjectives

I think the translation should be: illumina animum meum.

The word choice seems right to me.
According to my dictionary, animus (-i) can be translated as: soul, spirit, memory, will, pleasure, heart, character, mood, bravery, thorn.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for the great answer!